# Remove or change X-Frame-Options for one specific file in Laravel or in nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have a Laravel app where `X-Frame-Options` is currently `SAMEORIGIN`. I want to either remove or change it for one specific static html file. This file is not generated by blade, it's just a static html file.

I know that in Laravel I can do:

```
$response->headers->remove('X-Frame-Options');
```

And in nginx:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL";
```

or

```
proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
```

I've tried adding the following lines in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but that seems to break my whole website...

```
location /folder/file.html {
        proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
}
```

I think doing this in nginx is faster as it doesn't have to go through Laravel, but if that's not true and it's easier to set in Laravel then I'm open to that.

**Update**

First of all, I needed to put the `location` snippet inside the `server` part in the conf file...

Second, it looks like Laravel adds the `X-Frame-Options` header because after adding the location snippet correctly and restarting the server, it's still there.

Comment: What do you mean with >>I've tried adding the following lines in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but that seems to break my whole website...
? 
Which error yout get from nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like Laravel still added the header, but that wasn't the case. The part proxy_hide_header didn't work, in the end this worked:

```
server {
  location /folder/file.html {
    add_header X-Frame-Options "";
  }
}
```